# C# - Method must have a return type

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am having problems calling a method in C#, I keep getting the message "Method (calculate) must have a return type".

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }



    public class Hello : Form
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
        calculate();
    }


    public class Hello2 : Form
    {
        public void calculate()
        {
            Process.Start("test.exe");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`calculate();` is an invalid method signature in your `Hello` class. It is missing the return type and it also needs a body.

At a minimum the signature should look like:

```
public class Hello : Form
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    void calculate() {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Hello : Form
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    **calculate();**
}
```

Is not valid because calculate() is not a constructor or method. You cannot call methods from the class scope.

Answer (score 2):

if `calculate` doesn't return anything you have to be explicit and say that with `void`.

It also needs a method body (unless it is marked as `abstract`).

```
public class Hello : Form
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    void calculate() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are trying to call it inside the body of a class. You cannot do this in C#. You can only call methods from other methods or constructors. The syntax parser thinks that you are trying to define a new method and forgot to mention the type.