# "Method must have a return type" error

Tags: c#

```
 public StudentClass(char level, int number, Teacher educator, int maxStudents)
    {
        this.level = level;
        this.number = number;
        this.educator = educator;
        this.numStudents = 0;
        this.students = new Student[maxStudents];

    }
    public StudentClass(char level, int number)
    {
        this.level = level;
        this.number = number;
        this.numStudent = 0;
        this.students = new Student[STANDART];
    }
```

It gives me an error in words - StudentClass
please help me ....
thank u

Comment: Please post the exact text of the error and the line on which it occurs. In the case you're showing, these two methods appear to be constructors, so the containing class needs to be named `StudentClass` (hint, show this part of the code).

Comment: What @AbeMiessler is trying to say, is that you are not giving enough information. It's a plea for help not a question. YOU got to do your part before people can help you...

Comment: Include the class definition for this type.

Comment: The exactly the same question is asked many times already and using search engine could give you info. Clicking F1 on error would bring you to MSDN page explaining it. Searching on error code (CSXXXXX) is another option to get info... -3 seems standard for this type of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496481/c-sharp-method-must-have-a-return-type.

Comment: Hi, welcome at StackOverflow. When you asked this question did you notice the list 'Questions that may already have your answer'? As said, your question is not new. Also, when you ask a question often people ask for clarification and details. Always be quick to respond to such comments otherwise people will get frustrated and move on and you won't get the almost instant help you could have gotten.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from constructors all methods in C# must specify a return type. If you do not want to return a value that type should be `void`.

It looks like there's a decent chance both those methods are constructors if that is the case then the name must match the class name exactly or the compiler won't recognize it as such and will give an error.